# How to capture the specific field of a response of http request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My response of http request is like below.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetFoodFillPickingListDetailsResponse xmlns="http://Stock.Cssm.ServiceContracts/2007/06">
        <FoodFillPickingListDetails>
            <string>**77a3f4a3-8465-4dff-805b-08810aea1603|00712385**|RAW HOND PRAWN|F02F|FROZEN|Frozen|15|2|12|||False||||12/01/2018 18:48:23|False</string>
            <string>**77a3f4a3-8465-4dff-805b-08810aea1603|00712392**|CKD HOND PRAWN|F02F|FROZEN|Frozen|15|2|12|||False||||12/01/2018 18:48:23|False</string>
            <string>**77a3f4a3-8465-4dff-805b-08810aea1603|00570039**|MADAGASCAN PRWN|F02F|FROZEN|Frozen|15|2|12|||False||||12/01/2018 18:48:23|False</string>
            <string>**77a3f4a3-8465-4dff-805b-08810aea1603|00452472**|XL G/LAND 350G|F02F|FROZEN|Frozen|15|2|12|||False||||12/01/2018 18:48:23|False</string>
        </FoodFillPickingListDetails>
    </GetFoodFillPickingListDetailsResponse>
</s:Body>
```

I need to parse the bolded data from above response and use it in the next request as below xml.

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SaveFoodFillPickingListDetailsResponse xmlns="http://Stock.Cssm.ServiceContracts/2007/06">
        <FoodFillPickingListDetails>
            <string>77a3f4a3-8465-4dff-805b-08810aea1603|00712385</string>
            <string>77a3f4a3-8465-4dff-805b-08810aea1603|00712392</string>
            <string>77a3f4a3-8465-4dff-805b-08810aea1603|00570039</string>
            <string>77a3f4a3-8465-4dff-805b-08810aea1603|00452472</string>
        </SaveFillPickingListDetails>
    <SaveFoodFillPickingListDetailsResponse>
</s:Body>
```

I'm trying with Xpath extractor, but I'm able to extract only the complete value of '<string>' and for only 1 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe better idea is using regular expressions for this as text operations is not something XPath is designed for, it is still possible but kind of tricky.

The relevant regular expression to get everything between `<string>` and second occurrence of `|` would be something like

```
<string>[^\|]*\|[^\|]*
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex Demo]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Regular expressions in Perl: Summary With Examples](http://jkorpela.fi/perl/regexp.html)